# Adding view to fragment viewgroup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view

I want to update fragment view hierarchy on some event (button press, etc)

Here is my code of fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories_preview, container, false);
    }

    private void updateMainView()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   

        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.images_preview_container);
        container.removeAllViews();

        int layoutId = R.layout.list_preview;
        int cellLayoutId = R.layout.list_image_view;

        resultView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
        resultView.setAdapter(new ImagesListAdapter(inflater, cellLayoutId, this.imagesList));
        resultView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
        container.addView(resultView);
    }

    // Other functions
    // ...
}
```

Function updateMainView() called when pressing button. View isn't appearing in fragment.

I tryed to add empty colored view:

```
View test = new View(this.getActivity());
test.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
test.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
container.addView(test);
```

No result.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Weird that your code isn't working because I tested the same code and it worked. What if you set height and width for test view to be 50px for example?

Comment: There was mistake in container layout description